# How to display items in combobox using windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I'm trying to display items in a combobox but nothing appears. I used the property:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 

    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 1");         
    }
```

To add in an item but when I run my app the item doesn't show in the drop downlist.

I looked at a lot of MSDN articles but none have worked or perhaps I'm not getting it.

Is there something I'm missing with this?

Comment: Why are you trying to add it on the index changed? do you have any items in the combobox already?

Comment: No item's added to the combobox beforehand. Just trying to code it in by using Add() though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `ComboBox` is initially empty, then your `SelectedIndexChanged` event is never getting fired because there is no selection *to* change.  I would add the items to the `ComboBox` somewhere else, perhaps in an `Init()` function.

You might be misunderstanding how they work.  Once you create the combobox and add it to some kind of UI container, the .NET Framework takes care of displaying it and showing the items it is initialized with when you click it.  You don't need to manually handle making items show.  Basically, what I'm getting at is if you make a combobox and add some items to it, then it will automatically show them whenever the control is clicked.

The `SelectedIndexChanged` event is used typically used to make something happen when you select a different item from the `CheckBox` then what it is currently showing.

Comment: Ok great that works... lol I spent so much time on this and just placing this code outside of the event handler function is all it took to work.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding an item (presumably the first) in the SelectedIndexChanged event.  If there are no items in the combo box then the selected index can not change and the item will not get added.

Answer (score 1):

The attached code will only add the item "Item 1" if you change the selected index of the combo box control.  The selected index will only change if you click the combo box and select a new item.  Thus, the item will never be displayed.

Try adding items at compile time (using the Items property in Visual studio with the combo box selected) or adding code to your OnLoad form event.